# Abrir o calendário da ngxDaterangepickerMd com a data inicial e final com mesmo dia

Tags: javascript, datepicker, angular-8

Estou tendo [esse mesmo problema](https://github.com/fetrarij/ngx-daterangepicker-material/issues/470) relatado por um usuário no próprio plugin, porém instalei a versão que comentaram (4.0.1) e mesmo assim o problema persiste:
O que estou fazendo para o caso é pegando esta data do JSON e convertendo ela para o formato do plugin "moment", pois no json ela vem com o formato de string:

```
{
    "endDate": "2023-02-28T03:00:00.000Z",
    "startDate": "2023-02-28T03:00:00.000Z"
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
formatDate(e) {
    const formatDate = (date) => moment(new Date(date)).toDate();
    if (e && e.startDate && e.endDate) {
        return {
          endDate:formatDate(e.endDate) || null, 
          startDate:formatDate(e.startDate) || null
        } 
    } else {
      return null;
    }
}

ranges: any = {
    [this.translatePeriodKeys('Últimos 7 dias')]: [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
    [this.translatePeriodKeys('Últimos 15 dias')]: [moment().subtract(14, 'days'), moment()],
    [this.translatePeriodKeys('Últimos 30 dias')]: [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
    [this.translatePeriodKeys('Este mês')]: [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
    [this.translatePeriodKeys('Último mês')]: [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
    [this.translatePeriodKeys('Este trimestre')]: [moment().set('month', (this.initialMonthOfQuarter[moment().quarter()] - 1)).startOf('month'), moment().set('month', (this.initialMonthOfQuarter[moment().quarter()] + 1)).endOf('month')],
    [this.translatePeriodKeys('Último trimestre')]: [moment().subtract(this.getQuarterDates(moment()).substractInitialMonth, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(this.getQuarterDates(moment()).substractEndMonth, 'month').endOf('month')],
    [this.translatePeriodKeys('Este ano')]: [moment().startOf('year'), moment()]
}
```

O comportamento esperado no calendário deveria ser mostrar na primeira coluna, o mês com dia selecionado, e na segunda coluna o mês corrente, conforme é ilustrado abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na HTML está assim, não sei se tem alguma configuração que possa estar causando isso:

```
<input type="text" ngxDaterangepickerMd class="form-control input-date-picker"
          [(ngModel)]="item.modelDate" 
          [placeholder]="item?.placeholder"
          [locale]="getLocale()" 
          [showDropdowns]="data?.showDropdowns" 
          [showClearButton]="data?.showClearButton"
          [lockStartDate]="false" 
          (datesUpdated)="selectionChanges(item, [item.modelDate], $event);"
          [alwaysShowCalendars]="true"
          [ranges]="data?.ranges"
          [customRangeDirection]="false" 
          showCancel="data?.showCancel || false" 
          [attr.id]="data?.uniqueId || item?.id"
/>
```

O [plugin é o ngx-daterangepicker-material](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-daterangepicker-material)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eu resolvi o problema fazendo as datas ficarem válidas quando amba são as mesmas:

```
formatDate(e) {
    if (e && e.startDate && e.endDate) {
        if(e.startDate == e.endDate) {
           e.startDate =new Date(e.startDate);
           e.endDate = new Date(e.endDate);
        }
        return {
          startDate: moment(e.startDate).toDate() || null,
          endDate: moment(e.endDate).toDate() || null
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }
  }
```